# How convert System.Byte[] To System.UInt64[]?

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion

I try converting any C# object to System.UInt64[].

```
System.Byte[] to System.UInt64[].
double[] to System.UInt64[].
int[] to System.UInt64[].
```

Example, convert object f1, f2 to ulong b[]

```
 object f1 = new Byte[3] { 1, 2, 3 };  
 ulong b[]  = Convert<ulong>(f1); //---  ?

 object f2 = new double[3] { 1, 2, 3 };  
 b  = Convert<ulong>(f2); //---  ?
```

Output

```
b[0] = 1
b[1] = 2
b[3] = 3
```

tell me how to write the function code `Convert<T>(object value)`, where T output type value ulong ?

restrictions: Framework 2.0, input type can be obtained from the object f.

It turned out the only way to make

```
 ulong[] b = Array.ConvertAll((byte[])f, element => Convert.ToUInt64(element));
```

Unfortunately input type is not necessarily be byte []

Comment: You'll need to explain how you expect an array of 3 bytes to be converted into a `ulong`. So that we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with this, but maybe there are better decisions

```
    static T[] MyConvert<T>(object value){
        T[] ret = null;
        if (value is Array)
        {
            Array arr = value as Array;
            ret = new T[arr.Length];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length; i++ )
            {
                ret[i] =  (T)Convert.ChangeType(arr.GetValue(i), typeof(T));.
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a linq expression:

```
System.Byte[] source = new System.Byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
// does not work: System.UInt64[] target = source.Cast<System.UInt64>().ToArray();
System.UInt64[] target = source.Select(b => (System.UInt64)b).ToArray();
```

This works for all datatypes in source which can be casted to 'System.UInt64'.

**Edit:**
As [Thomas Levesque](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273075/how-convert-system-byte-to-system-uint64#comment41220900_26273319) pointed out `Cast<System.UInt64>()`does not work here, so we must use a `Select(ConvertFunction)` here.

Comment: No, it won't work in this case. It only works for reference conversions.

Comment: @askeet That's tough. If you want to specify additional constraints, they need to go in the question. Please heed this advice in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.ConvertAll`:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
ulong[] ulongs = Array.ConvertAll<byte, ulong>(b => (ulong)b);
```